# Vuejs input form Unexpected token

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make a VueJS form with generated number validation at random.org. All the data comes to me, everything seems to be fine, but the problem itself is in the form.

I have a form:

```
<form action="https://api.random.org/verify" method="post" target="_blank">
  <input type='hidden' name='format' value='json'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='random' v-model="{{ game.random }}"/>
  <input type='hidden' name='signature' v-model="{{ game.signature }}"/>
  <input class="check-on-random-org-btn" type="submit" v-model="Ticket: {{ game.number }}">
</form>
```

But when i make `npm run watch` i recevied:

```
invalid expression: Unexpected token '{' in

  {{ game.random }}

  Raw expression: v-model="{{ game.random }}"
```

But i already use `v-model=""`. Where can be my problem?

Comment: you don't need to add {{}} while using v-model

Answer (score 0):

remove `{{}}`.

```
<form action="https://api.random.org/verify" method="post" target="_blank">
  <input type='hidden' name='format' value='json'/>
  <input type='hidden' name='random' v-model="game.random"/>
  <input type='hidden' name='signature' v-model="game.signature"/>
  <input class="check-on-random-org-btn" type="submit" :value="`Ticket: ${ game.number }`">
</form>
```